# How can I replace an entire column in a csv file with the appropriate foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, ssms

I'm working on a stock trading project, and I have stock data saved as csv files in this format.

| symbol | date | open | high | low | close | vol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 20220627 | 24.38 | 24.38 | 24.365 | 24.365 | 500 |

I'm currently working on the database design, and I'm using SQL Server & SSMS. The issue is with the schema I've created, I don't have a table that shares exactly the same columns as this csv file. Therefore it's not as straight forward as just importing or bulk inserting the data directly into a table.

In my schema I came up with a Stock table

| id | symbol | company_name | stock_exchange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

And a Stock Data table

| id | stock_id | date | open | high | low | close | vol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

The csv data ultimately needs to go into my Stock Data table, however I need to figure out a way to convert the stock symbol to the correct id that each stock is being assigned by my Stock table. Is this an issue with my design or is there a simple way to handle this that I cannot seem to find? I had considered simply reading the csv data into a temporary table and then correctly inserting the data into the Stock Data table, but I wasn't sure how to easily accomplish that since I'll be inserting thousands of rows.

You can view my full diagram here - https://lucid.app/lucidchart/28591ceb-6574-4e22-a5ce-284cada1d832/edit?invitationId=inv_d5eb35d3-9bd0-4ba0-aa95-e7d70ca50562#

Comment: you import the data in a temporary table and the run a procdure on that table and empty it, the rest is simple sql

Comment: ETL is a complex issue and that is what you are attempting to do. An ETL tool - like SSIS - can often do these transformations in a more robust and effective manner than writing code your self in a language that you might not have mastered. In this case, you can load your data into a staging table and then validate and transform it before or during insertion into the actual table (or tables). And I suggest you stop adding an identity column as the primary key of every table. Your stock data table (a terrible name) has a very good natural key.

Comment: Thanks for the help nbk & SMor! I'm still terrible at database design and I agree that I need to rename that table. A quick follow up question though @SMor, which column or columns are you suggesting make a good natural key on my stock data table?

Comment: A key is a set/list of columns for which a subrow value is unique in a table. So possible keys are? PS "since I'll be inserting thousands of rows" How is this a reason? Why "since"? PS Time to read some textbook(s) on IM & DB design & querying. PS Please ask a new (specific researched non-duplicate) question (if you still need to after research) in a new post. (But beginner questions are already asked & answered.) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

SSIS can do the lookup before doing the insert.  This would be a typical ETL.  I would likely use ELT and avoid a complicated SSIS package.  There is no extract because you already have the csv file.  Bulk load or use simple SSIS package to load the file.  Then join the loaded data to the lookup table to do the insert to the StockData table.  (You can do the join and insert in the SSIS package as a T-SQL execution.  Or create a job to do the bulk insert and T-SQL.)